# Abort XHR on timeout event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to abort XHR request on timeout event, but it's not working. Syntax is next:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', url , true);

req.timeout = 5000;
req.ontimeout = function () {
  req.abort();
};
```

So if XHR request is not finished in 5 seconds code should abort request. If I only write req.abort(), XHR request will perform.

Comment: try setting `.ontimeout` before calling `open()`

Comment: @DLeh same thing again. PS I'm using Mozilla Firefox 38

Comment: Or maybe XHR object is already destroyed on timeout event so there is nothing to abort?

Comment: usually when something is timed out, it has already aborted. that usually is the meaning of a timeout. put some `console.log()`s in there in the `ontimeout` function and in a `done()` function and see which cases are being hit